# How to replace a string in Pyspark dataframe column from another column in Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Experts, this is minor, but I am not able to just get it right.

```
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|table         |query                                                     |date               |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|AGENT         |select * from table where DW_EFFECTIVE_DATE_PARTITION ='X'|2019-12-24 00:00:00|
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

All I want in this dataframe is to change column query to:

```
select * from table where DW_EFFECTIVE_DATE_PARTITION ='2019-12-24 00:00:00'
```

I tried:

```
>>> dfX.withColumn('query',regexp_replace('query',"'X'","'" + dfX['d'] + "'")).show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Desired Output:

```
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|table         |query                                                                       |date             |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|AGENT         |select * from table where DW_EFFECTIVE_DATE_PARTITION ='2019-12-24 00:00:00'|2019-12-24 00:00:00|
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace` with `expr` so shat you could replace a string by another column value:

```
replace_expr = """regexp_replace(query,"'X'",concat("'", date, "'"))"""
df.withColumn("query", expr(replace_expr)).show(truncate=False)
```

Gives:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|table|query                                                                       |date               |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|AGENT|select * from table where DW_EFFECTIVE_DATE_PARTITION ='2019-12-24 00:00:00'|2019-12-24 00:00:00|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectExpr` instead of `withColumn`:

```py
>>> df.selectExpr("table","regexp_replace(query, 'X', date) as query", "date").show(truncate=False)
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|table|query                                                                       |date               |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|AGENT|select * from table where DW_EFFECTIVE_DATE_PARTITION ='2019-12-24 00:00:00'|2019-12-24 00:00:00|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_string(s):
  if s == "A":
    return "a"
  else:
    return "b"
replace_string_udf = spark.udf.register("replace_string", replace_string, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("new_column", replace_string_udf("old_column_name"))
```